# SQL Azure reports by e-mail?

Tags: reporting, azure-sql-database

I am new to Windows Azure and SQL Azure and was wondering if there is a way that I can export the reports (on my reportserver) that I created and e-mail them to for example and administrator automatically like every week?

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new to both Windows Azure and SQL Azure, I would suggest the following:

1. SQL Azure Reporting is still in Preview (or CTP) mode so there are limited functionalities available.
2. SQL Azure reporting preview provides following 3 scenarios:

   2.1 Embed Microsoft reports in Web or client applications

   2.2 Design, publish, and view reports (.rdl) and report-related items on a SQL Azure Reporting report server.

   2.3 Interact with the report server Web service by using SOAP API calls.
3. So when you are using SQL Azure Reporting Preview you can generate the reports however to send these reports via email you need a front end to take care of job or custom code running on-premise connected to SQL Azure Reporting service.

   3.1 This front end could be a Windows Azure Web Role (using 3rd party email provider or online MS Exchange to send email) or your own SQL Azure reporting service sending emails by using custom code.

   3.2 You can also write a client application talking to Reporting Service Web Service over SOAP to get reports and then email to required destination.

More information on SQL Azure Reporting Preview is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg430129.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! :) I just wanted to know if it was possible but the options you gave are a really good suggestions and I can get started again :). Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your reportserver is running on Azure? Azure doesn't have an SMTP server so basically what you will need to do is

1) Use a third-party SMTP server (Gmail is free) to send out the emails. Azure recently have a deal with sendgrid who provide SMTP and email services as well.
2) Write a little application that runs in a worker role and periodically generates the reports and sends them out.